# Asymptotic Expansions of Exponential Integral function

Tags: special-functions

In [NIST equation 8.20.2](http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.20) what is meant by $(p)_{k}$

$$\mathop{E_{p}}\nolimits\!\left(z\right)\sim\frac{e^{-z}}{z}\sum_{k=0}^{%
\infty}(-1)^{k}\frac{\left(p\right)_{k}}{z^{k}},$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Pochhammer symbol defined in http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.iii
$$(p)_k = p\cdot(p+1)\cdot(p+1)\dots(p+k-1)=\frac{\Gamma(p+k)}{\Gamma(p)}$$

Comment: as you know the limits of the $sum$ is from $0 to \infty$, but if I choose large number I will not get better result, however, if I choose small number the result looks much better.
what is the reason behind that?

Comment: This is an asymptotic expansion, **not a convergent series**. With AE you normally
use only a few terms, and often there are error estimates (see eg the
well-known Stirling AE for the Gamma function). In your case there is no
error term listed, but I guess you can compute one from
http://dlmf.nist.gov/8.20.E1.